# How to create effect of stack of view for collection view?

Tags: swift, animation, stack, collectionview, effect

I am try create effect like few view stack over other for collection view, I am not build effect like this in the past and can't understand how I can create this effect programmatically without images?

Can somebody explain me how I can repeat this effect or post link to code of tutorial?

Example of this effect below:

[image: stack effect]

Comment: It isn't clear what you need help with. You want to create the stacked, translucent rounded rectangles that look like they are stacked in 3D? Do you just want that appearance under each cell, or are those stacks of tiles supposed to be selectable in some way?

Comment: If you just want translucent overlapping rounded rectangles like that you should be able to do it with a few shape layers installed under the cell's content view's layer.

Comment: "You want to create the stacked, translucent rounded rectangles that look like they are stacked in 3D?" Yes I am want this effect for each cell, I need just create shape layer one each other for this effect? or I am can use another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get that effect you'd need to add layers under the collection view cells' layers that are smaller and shifted down a little from the cell's layers. You'd use the same background color as the cell on each layer that had a lower alpha than the cell's layer.

I created a sample project that demonstrates how to get the effect:

https://github.com/DuncanMC/CustomCollectionViewCell.git

The cells look like this:

[image]

The heavy lifting is in a custom subclass of UICollectionViewCell that I called `MyCollectionViewCell`

Here is that class:

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    public var contentCornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            contentView.layer.cornerRadius = contentCornerRadius
            sizeLayerFrames()
        }

    }

    public var fraction: CGFloat = 0.075 { // What percent to shrink & shift the faded layers down (0.075 = 7.5%)
        didSet {
            sizeLayerFrames()
        }
    }
    private var layerMask =   CAShapeLayer()
    private var layer1 = CALayer()
    private var layer2 = CALayer()


    // Use this function to set the cell's background color.
    // (You can't set the view's background color, since we Don't clip the view to it's bounds.)

    // Be sure to set the background color explicitly, since by default it sets a random color that will persist
    // as the cells are recylced, causing your cell colors to move around as the user scrolls
    public func setBackgroundColor(_ color: UIColor)  {
        var red: CGFloat = 0
        var green: CGFloat = 0
        var blue: CGFloat = 0
        color.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: nil)
        contentView.layer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor

        //Make the first extra layer have the same color as the cell's layer, but with alpha 0.25
        layer1.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 0.25).cgColor

        //Make the second extra layer have the same color as the cell's layer, but with alpha 0.125
        layer2.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 0.125).cgColor
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var customLabel: UILabel!

    //Do The initial setup once the cell is loaded.
    //Note that t
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        contentView.layer.masksToBounds = false

        // Color each cell's layer some random hue (change to set whatever color you desire.)
        //For testing, use a color based on a random hue and fairly high random brightness.
        let hue = CGFloat.random(in: 0...360)
        let brightness = CGFloat.random(in: 0.8...1.0)
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        setBackgroundColor(UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: 1, brightness: brightness, alpha: 1))


        // Make the inside of the shape layer white (opaque), The color doesn't matter - just that the alpha value is 1
        // and the outside clear (transparent)
        layerMask.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        layerMask.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        //With the even/odd rule, the inner shape will not be filled (we'll only fill the part NOT in the inner shape)
        layerMask.fillRule = .evenOdd
        contentCornerRadius = 30


        sizeLayerFrames()

        contentView.layer.addSublayer(layer1)
        layer1.addSublayer(layer2)
        layer1.mask = layerMask
    }

    private func sizeLayerFrames() {
        layer1.cornerRadius = contentCornerRadius
        layer2.cornerRadius = contentCornerRadius


        let viewBounds = bounds //Use the layer's bounds as the starting point for the extra layers.
        var frame1 = viewBounds
        frame1.origin.y += viewBounds.size.height * fraction
        frame1.origin.x += viewBounds.size.width * fraction

        frame1.size.width *= CGFloat(1 - 2 * fraction)
        layer1.frame = frame1
        var frame2 = viewBounds
        frame2.origin.y += viewBounds.size.height * 0.75 * fraction
        frame2.origin.x += viewBounds.size.width  * fraction

        frame2.size.width *= CGFloat(1 - 4 * fraction)
        layer2.frame = frame2

        //Create a mask layer to clip the extra layers.
        var maskFrame = viewBounds

        //We are going to install the mask on layer1, so offeset the frame to cover the whole view contents
        maskFrame.origin.y -= viewBounds.size.height * fraction
        maskFrame.origin.x -= viewBounds.size.width * fraction
        maskFrame.size.height += viewBounds.size.height * fraction * 1.75
        layerMask.frame = maskFrame
        maskFrame = viewBounds
        let innerPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: maskFrame, cornerRadius: 30)
        maskFrame.size.height += viewBounds.size.height * fraction * 1.75
        let combinedPath = UIBezierPath(rect: maskFrame)
        combinedPath.append(innerPath)
        layerMask.path = combinedPath.cgPath
    }

    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            sizeLayerFrames()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Duncan for your help :). Very good explanation.

Comment: Note that the code I posted will need some adjustment. Right now the extra layers land on top of the collection view cell's layer. I'll post an update that adds a mask to those layers when I get a chance.

Comment: Ok, I understand you. I am will be reading more about what is the mask. I did not work with this in ago it's interesting feature for me, thank you.

Comment: If I did it again I think I would add non-opaque subviews to the collection view cell's content view, with low alpha background colors. I could have put the subviews **under** the content view and avoided all the complexity of creating the mask layer.

Comment: Maybe, I am will try this way. Thank you for advice )